# How do I wriite a query statement to select multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, select, join

There are three tables in mysql.

**Table 1:**

```
 create table a1{
 no int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
 member_no int,
 channel varchar(50)
 };
```

**Table 2:**

```
create table a2(
no int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
member_no int, 
title varchar(100) not null,
description varchar(400),
video_name varchar(100)
);
```

and **Table 3:**

```
 create table a3(
 no int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
 member_no int, 
 video_name varchar(100)
);
```

I want to select `a1.channel` that satisfies the same condition.
How do I write query statement?

This is what I have so far:

```
select * from a2 a join a3 b on a.video_name=b.video_name and b.member_no=#          
     {member_no};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obtuse table names don't help (a1, a2, a3) with obtuse aliases (a,b) don't make for great comprehension, but perhaps this will assist.

```
select * 
from a2 a 
join a3 b on on a.member_no = b.member_no and a.video_name = b.video_name 
join a1 c on a.member_no = c.member_no
where a.member_no= {member_no}
;
```